# View the end of a long string in ABAP debugger

Tags: string, debugging, abap

In my ABAP function module, I have a string containing some megabyte of printable characters.

During debugging with se80, I would like to see the end of the string.

How to see the last 20 characters of the string?

Comment: Typing +n(m) in the debugger after the string variable name does not work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can see the technical type in the debugger which shows the actual length of a string. Here is an example.

```
REPORT ZZZ.

DATA(g_string) = `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`.

BREAK-POINT.
```

In this example the technical type is `CString{52}`. With this information you can calculate the offset by yourself `52 - 20 = 32` and then type your variable like that in the debugger `g_string+32(20)`.

Example screenshots for a huge XString variable:

- **Backend debugger** : [image]
- **ADT debugger** : [image]

Comment: If you don't mind, I edited your answer to propose 2 screenshots (because I am just having the case).

Comment: Everything that improves the answer is highly welcome.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Html or Text Browser in Detail Display tab. Double click to variable for opening it.

[image]

Comment: Not recommended if the string or xstring variable is very big, it can be very slow to display... (60 MB -> timeout ;-)). Note that the latest ADT debugger version displays only the first 5003 characters (at least for xstring) -> use Jagger's solution.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to download the long variable in the debugger to a local text file and then check it via Notepad, for example.

You can do this using the 'wrench' icon:

[image]

In the next popup, just choose ASCII.

The tricky part of course is to find a solution to upload the same value to a different system. I guess that's what we're all here for. The same icon cannot be used for that, so my guess is we're still stuck manually moving transports around.